# How is Object Oriented Javascript used for DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, oop, dom

I understand the main principle of OOP and I somewhat know how to implement it into JS.

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.speak = function(msg) {
        console.log('Person says:' + msg);
    }
}

var dad = new Person('David');
dad.speak('I am your dad!');
```

The script above does nothing more than printing out a message in the console. I don't understand how we approach the DOM with this technique. Maybe something like this?:

```
function Person(target, name) {
    this.target = target;
    this.name = name;
    this.speak = function(msg) {
        this.target.find('.speech-bubble').html(msg);
    }
}

var dad = new Person($('#dad'), 'David');
dad.speak('I am your dad!');
```

Although this doesn't seem like a good approach.

How do we manipulate the DOM with objects, methods, constructors etc. through OO Javascript?

Comment: Try taking a look at MDN's explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Comment: you have two arguments for the Person object so it would be `var dad = new Person($('#dad'), 'David');` then `dad.speak('I am your dad!');`

Comment: @oliv37 Oops, corrected it ;)

Comment: By the way, you are using jQuery with `$('#dad')` and `find('.speech-bubble')` so it's not plain javascript anymore

Comment: I know. I could've used document.getElementById, but as it basically does the same thing it doesn't really matter. It's just that I don't know if the code as a whole is a good practice or not.

Comment: It's *Document **Object** Model*. There's nothing you need to do but use it, everything is already modelled for you.

Comment: Object methods and properties are useful for modifying or retrieving HTML or CSS attributes of DOM objects, i.e. `thisElement.style.display = 'block';` or `myVar = thatElement.value;`.

Comment: @StefanvanLingen I'm also having the same question, if you got the answer can you please share the correct source. thanks

Answer (score 7):

In relation to OO, if you are going to adopt for your DOM facing code, you are not too far of.

I'd say that a class should represent a component/element on the DOM. With it's methods being the state management part. But there is no correct answer here to be honest. This is but one way of designing OO with the DOM facing part.

Example:

```js
const basicClassName = 'component';
const basicTemplate = '<h1>This is my basic component</h1>';

class MyComponent {
  constructor(template = basicTemplate, className = basicClassName) {
    this.template = template;
    this.className = className;
    
    this.element = document.createElement('div');
    this.element.className = className;
    this.element.innerHTML = template;
    this.element.onclick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    this.element.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  }
  
  onClick() {
    this.element.classList.toggle('clicked');
  }
}

const component = new MyComponent();

const container = document.querySelector('.container');

container.appendChild(component.element);
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.component {
  display: block;
  padding: 1.3em;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px lightgray;
}


.clicked {
  background-color: papayawhip;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

What you need to understand is the concept of the `Prototype`.

When you create an instance using `new`, you are constructing an object based upon a prototype.

Consider the following:

```js
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.speak = function (msg) {
        console.log('Person says:' + msg);
    };
}
var dad = new Person('David');
dad.speak('I am your dad!');
console.log('Is dad.speak equal to dad.speak?', dad.speak === dad.speak);
var mom = new Person('David');
console.log('Is mom.speak equal to dad.speak?', mom.speak === dad.speak);
```

Each time you construct a new instance of `Person`, a new `speak` prototype now floats around somewhere in your logic. This is very inefficient.

To fix this, we need to modify the `prototype` of our function:

```js
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
Person.prototype.speak = function (msg) {
    console.log('Person says:' + msg);
};
var dad = new Person('David');
dad.speak('I am your dad!');
console.log('Is dad.speak equal to dad.speak?', dad.speak === dad.speak);
var mom = new Person('David');
console.log('Is mom.speak equal to dad.speak?', dad.speak === dad.speak);
```

This way, we only have the function created once, on the `prototype` which is inherited to all instances. This is easier to maintain and a lot more efficient.

Now we **can** extend DOM object via their `prototype`, but it isn't recommended because you start to mess with the web standards, making troubleshooting much more difficult.

```js
Array.prototype.isLengthGreaterThanFive = function(thisArg) {
  return this.length > 5;
};
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4].isLengthGreaterThanFive(), [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].isLengthGreaterThanFive());
```

A better way of handling this is to create extended objects or to simply use functions:

```js
//Using functions
function isLengthGreaterThanFive(array) {
  return array.length > 5;
}
console.log(isLengthGreaterThanFive([1, 2, 3, 4]), isLengthGreaterThanFive([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]));
```

```js
//Using a wrapper class
var MyArray = (function() {
  function MyArray(array) {
    if (array === void 0) {
      array = [];
    }
    this.array = array;
  }
  MyArray.prototype.isLengthGreaterThanFive = function() {
    return this.array.length > 5;
  };
  return MyArray;
}());
console.log(new MyArray([1, 2, 3, 4]).isLengthGreaterThanFive(), new MyArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]).isLengthGreaterThanFive());
```

The benefits of using a class is that we can extend upon our idea of the object:

```js
//Base class
function Person(firstname, lastname, says) {
    if (firstname === void 0) {
        firstname = "Leonado";
    }
    this.firstname = firstname;
    if (lastname === void 0) {
        lastname = "Da Vinci";
    }
    this.lastname = lastname;
    if (says === void 0) {
        says = "hello";
    }
    this.says = says;
}
//Base methods
Person.prototype.iAm = function () {
    return this.firstname + " " + this.lastname;
};
Person.prototype.Speak = function () {
    return this.says + " my name is " + this.iAm();
};
//Extended class
function Warrior(firstname, lastname, says) {
    //Call in constructor
    Person.call(this, firstname, lastname, says);
}
//Inheriting
Warrior.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Warrior.prototype.constructor = Warrior;
//Overruling "Speak"
Warrior.prototype.Speak = function () {
    return "My name is " + this.iAm() + ", " + this.says;
};
console.log([new Warrior("Peter", "Allan", "Ahoyhoy").Speak(), new Person("Peter", "Allan", "Ahoyhoy").Speak()]);
```

In the example above we extend the prototype of `Person` for `Warrior` so that we retain the functionality of `Person`, and then simply modify what's different about a `Warrior`. This way we get to reuse the prototype method `iAm`, and we can focus on only changing what needs to change in the `Speak` method.

**EDIT 1**

I noticed too late that the question had changed a little.

You can treat DOM elements like any other class in JavaScript. The following setup has all `Persons` sharing a single `DIV` to `speakUp`:

```js
var Person = (function () {
    function Person(age, firstname, lastname) {
        if (age === void 0) { age = 50; }
        if (firstname === void 0) { firstname = "Peter"; }
        if (lastname === void 0) { lastname = "Venkman"; }
        this.age = age;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    Person.prototype.speakUp = function () {
        Person.bubble.innerHTML = this.firstname + " " + this.lastname + " is " + this.age + " years old";
    };
    return Person;
}());
Person.bubble = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(Person.bubble);
setInterval(function () {
    var p = new Person(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
    p.speakUp();
}, 3000);
```

This could easily become a `DIV` per `Person`, or a refereced DOM object (document.getElementById) shared among all `Person`s.

**EDIT 2**

In response to your comment:

In JavaScript everything is in essence and `object`. You create a function it registers an `object` with the functions name and returns and `instance` of that `object`. Everything like `Arrays`, `Strings`, `DOM` elements and custom functions has some master `object` hidden behind the scenes. Every time a new `Array` or `DOM` element or whatever is created, it has a reference to its master object (called the prototype). This is called the prototype chain.

If you look on my second example above, when `dad.speak` is called JavaScript first searches the instance for a `speak` property, but it won't find one because we haven't assigned it the way we did in example one were it was instance specific.

JavaScript will then try one level up the `prototype` chain and here it will find a matching property and use this instead. This way we can alter the default behavior of custom **OR** existing elements in JavaScript.

The idea being, that if you have some property that all instances of a prototype should have, then we simply modify the prototype once and they will all `inherit` this property.

Think of it this way. If you were to describe all living things on earth in JavaScript you would want some form of groupings. For instance the first level would be something like an `Exists` object that carries a property for a name and an id. From here you you could create `Plant` and `Animal` and have them both inherit the prototype of `Exists`. Now we could create a `Flower` class that inherits `Plant` and a `Rose` class that inherits `Flower` and so on.

The idea is to apply you properties in a way that makes sense to human beings via inheritance (an owl can fly because it is a bird / a shark can swim because it is a fish). Binding them at the level that makes sense, inheriting in a logical pattern and using your time efficiently.

If you are still confused, try looking up `prototype` tutorials.

Here is a good Youtube video to explain it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMfcsYzj-9M

Comment: Prototype has always been a hard one for me. Sorry if I'm sounding dumb, but after your explanation I'm still having trouble to understand the use of prototype (with me being Dutch as a primary reason). To me it just seems like prototype is used to assign methods to a class, outside the class. Are you saying that the goal of prototype is to be responsive (automatically adapt to various subclasses/objects)?